# remove all the option from drop down list and then set a value in drop down list using javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp

on button click i'm redirecting to same page and remove all the options from drop down list

```
document.getElementById("name").options.length = 0;
```

i'm able to remove all the option from drop down list using this but i'm unable to set value for drop down list when i use

```
document.getElementById("name").value="${name}";
```

${name} contains the name which i have selected first time  and when i click on submit button i'm redirected to same page

so, now i want to set value of drop down list using ${name}
but i'm unable to do so...

little help will be highly appreciated 
sorry if the problem is silly but i'm a newbie

Comment: if you just want to set the value , why remove all the options?

Comment: @BhavikPatel,    because i want to save multiple entries for same name and i want that user is not able to change name till all the entries save

Answer (score 0):

You first need to add that option to the select element.

```
var opt = document.createElement('option');
opt.value = "${name}";
opt.innerHTML = "${name}";
document.getElementById("name").appendChild(opt);
```

Then set the value

```
document.getElementById("name").value="${name}";
```

Comment: @tom by the way, `document.getElementById("name").options.length = 0;` is not a cross-browser compatible way of removing all options. Search StackOverflow for a better way

Comment: if you know the best way ......can you help me with this problem also......otherwise i will search for the best way to do it..  and once again thanku for your help and precious time